# Single Responsibility Principle with JetPack Compose -- is there a reference guide?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, single-responsibility-principle, android-jetpack-compose

Since Jetpack Compose is following the Single Responsibility Principle I'm wondering where I can get my hands on a mapping of all the functions to "responsibilities", so to say. As an example, how could I have figured out on my own that the Surface function is responsible for the background color, and only the Surface function?

Comment: How would what you're looking for differ from just normal documentation?  For instance - `Surface` has a `color` parameter documented as "The background color", which would seem to answer your example.  I'm not sure what you mean by "only the Surface function" being responsible for background color - there are plenty of ways to draw a colored background.

Comment: Here's what I mean: "For example, if you want to set a background color for some components then you have to use a Surface Composable function. " from https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics/#3

Comment: How could I know that I have to use Surface to change the background color vs Container, for example?